# How to implement nested tables using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

New to GAS, programming in general and I'm trying to create a table inside a table.

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(filename);

  var body = doc.getBody();

  var oAddressBlock = [["Image Placeholder","Name and Address"]];

  var header = [[body.appendTable(oAddressBlock),"TimeSheet Block"]];

  body.appendTable(header);
```

I haven't been able to find anything on nesting tables but I have a feeling I'm missing something fundamental regarding child/parent relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax would be like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var oAddressBlock = [["Image Placeholder","Name and Address"]];
  var header = [['',"TimeSheet Block"]];
  var headerCell = body.appendTable(header).getCell(0,0);
  headerCell.appendTable(oAddressBlock);  
}
```

But unfortunately and as mentioned in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=894), this won't work for now, the issue tracker suggests a workaround that you could try.

Comment: Thanks, you've opened a new world with the issue tracker. It's another resource I didn't know existed.